# Does a tool exist that allows one to comb through the ai literature?

Tags: text-processing, language, nlp, academia

Does a tool exists, and I am specifically thinking of something LLM-based, that allow to ask such things as for example : “make me a timeline of the major papers in the field of object detection”, “are there papers that tried to apply transformers to the field of object detection ?”, or “list me all the papers that have been published that tries to improve the performances of a certain model” (These questions are just example, I do not need the answers to them). The tool could access the literature repositories online, or rely on a local database of publications, or both. Does something like this exist, or is someone attempting to create it ? Such a tool would be very useful for staying on top of current research, and determining the avenue of research that have not been yet explored.

Comment: Don't ChatGPT, Bard et al provide this functionality already?

Comment: Is having an obvious answer, reason to close?

Comment: ChatGPT and bard have an implicit knowledge of the literature, but they are rarely up to date and nothing guarantees that they will actually list all the papers you are looking for. They do not have access to the literature directly to comb trough it like the tool I am searching for.

Comment: Edit : indeed Google bard seems to work sufficiently well for the task I am asking for. Asking for something able to consult a database of papers directly to be perfectly of to date is probably a bit too futuristic for now.